# Trace of BFGS update matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, numerical-optimization

I'm having trouble proving that the trace of the following matrix is positive:
$$A_+ :=A - \frac{As^{T}sA}{s^{T}As}$$
where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix and $s \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $s \neq 0$. This matrix is almost the BFGS update matrix.

Applying the properties of the trace of a matrix, I got to the following expression:
$$\text{trace}(A_+) = \text{trace}(A) - \frac{||As||^2}{s^T A s}.$$

How should I conclude the statement that $\text{trace}(A_+) > 0$? I also tried proving that $A_+$ is a positive definite matrix but couldn't get anywhere.

Comment: Hints: A symmetric positive definite matrix is diagonalizable, and has all positive eigenvalues. Also the trace is the sum of eigenvalues. Finally, consider how large the second quantity can be.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Assume that $As \neq 0$ (if it were, then the denominator of $\frac{As^TsA}{s^TAs}$ would be zero). Let $u_1$ denote the unit vector in the direction of $As$, and extend this vector into an orthonormal basis $\{u_1,u_2,\dots,u_n\}$ of $\Bbb R^n$. Note that
$$
\operatorname{Tr}(A_+) = \sum_{i=1}^n u_i^TA_+u_i \geq u_1 ^TA_+u_1.
$$

---

Regarding the proof that $A_+$ is positive semidefinite: note that any $x \in \Bbb R^n$ can be written as $x = x_1 + x_2$ where $x_1$ is parallel to $u_1$ and $x_2$ is orthogonal to $u_1$.  Write
$$
x^TA_+x = (x_1 + x_2)^TA_+(x_1 + x_2) = x_1^TA_+x_1 + x_1^TA_+x_2 + x_2^TA_+x_1 + x_2^TA_+x_2.
$$
Of course, if you prove this statement first, then you get the statement about the trace for free.

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll try this approach.